# publishToPDP. Exception while sending SOAP request

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have successfully added a policy to the PAP.
[image]

I try now to publish it to the PDP using the SOAP interface.
Here is my request, but I get a 500 Error "Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method publishToPDP"
I've just set the minimum parameters as version, order and action are optional.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:publishToPDP>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <xsd:policyIds>policy-3</xsd:policyIds>
      </xsd:publishToPDP>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried with and without "". same error.

Could somebody help me ?
Thanks a lot for your support

Regards

vpl

Answer (score 2):

I've open the HTTP port on the wsoo2 and ran the client java sample http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/27/xacml-policy-administration/
By sniffing the network trace with Wireshark I was able to retrieve the SOAP requests I was looking for.
For the PublishToPDP here is the valid request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns3:publishToPDP xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
         <ns3:policyIds>policy-3</ns3:policyIds>
         <ns3:version xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="1" />
         <ns3:action>CREATE</ns3:action>
         <ns3:order>0</ns3:order>
      </ns3:publishToPDP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I suspect that the action and/or order are not so optional as described in the interface...

Regards
Vpl

Answer (score 0):

you should set all elements of API like this :

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <xsd:publishToPDP>
         <xsd:policyIds>policy_1</xsd:policyIds>
         <xsd:action>PUBLISH_POLICY</xsd:action>
         <xsd:version>1</xsd:version>
         <xsd:enabled>true</xsd:enabled>
         <xsd:order>0</xsd:order>
      </xsd:publishToPDP>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

then it should return :

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:publishToPDPResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
         <ns:return xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      </ns:publishToPDPResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```